# gvim window completely frozen

Tags: gvim, redraw

I have a problem with gvim on Fedora 30: when opening a file, the content is displayed, but then the window is never refreshed.

Already tried a lot of different solutions, with no success: CTRL-L does not refresh the window, neither does typing :redraw.

However it's just the rendering: if I type any command blindly (including :q), it is executed and the file is changed.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling? (Also welcome to [vi.se]!)

Comment: Tried right now, still stuck.

Comment: The solution to all problems: just reboot. It worked. Thanks anyway.